# Character-to-string converter

Tags: c#, converting

I created a program that will convert a 3-character combo into a 3-string combo. I used a lot of `if` statements to accomplish the conversion. I'm wondering if there is any way to reduce the lines of code and possibly make it more efficient.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Adow
{
    public partial class AdowForm : Form
    {
        private string FirstCharacter;
        private string SecondCharacter;
        private string ThirdCharacter;

        private string A = "0NFGSosLPI";
        private string B = "izNclMYrUO";
        private string C = "t7SjxAlxp5";
        private string D = "CeA7dwvVxY";
        private string E = "6kF4qi5bmt";
        private string F = "WuuQpKLN7n";
        private string G = "jy24ZxU7Ok";
        private string H = "8j0RAVF1Ka";
        private string I = "h9g173xKDV";
        private string J = "ypEeaBAzBx";
        private string K = "HNhqhtYMaU";
        private string L = "4qUvzJfvRA";
        private string M = "jJjAfk4m1y";
        private string N = "iF9d70yyf5";
        private string O = "9VlQkb0VKN";
        private string P = "nEdrSFCVTO";
        private string Q = "3ducfBmoi5";
        private string R = "atWIdmnsnG";
        private string S = "4edrAImSrq";
        private string T = "aUhZY1uDA5";
        private string U = "ARHxAVFnnN";
        private string V = "VKNXzjDlrx";
        private string W = "9eDu4vY24O";
        private string X = "tWAspyXsMM";
        private string Y = "DY89qcdHnP";
        private string Z = "SNSjmtyVtw";

        public AdowForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ConvertButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //////////////////////////////////////////////////
            //                                              //
            //     FirstCharacter                           //
            //                                              //
            //////////////////////////////////////////////////

            if (FirstCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("A", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                FirstCharacter = A;
            }
            else if (FirstCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("B", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                FirstCharacter = B;
            }
            else if (FirstCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("C", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                FirstCharacter = C;
            }
            else if (FirstCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("D", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                FirstCharacter = D;
            }
            else if (FirstCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("E", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                FirstCharacter = E;
            }
            else if (FirstCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("F", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                FirstCharacter = F;
            }
            else if (FirstCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("G", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                FirstCharacter = G;
            }
            else if (FirstCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("H", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                FirstCharacter = H;
            }
            else if (FirstCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("I", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                FirstCharacter = I;
            }
            else if (FirstCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("J", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                FirstCharacter = J;
            }
            else if (FirstCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("K", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                FirstCharacter = K;
            }
            else if (FirstCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("L", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                FirstCharacter = L;
            }
            else if (FirstCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("M", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                FirstCharacter = M;
            }
            else if (FirstCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("N", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                FirstCharacter = N;
            }
            else if (FirstCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("O", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                FirstCharacter = O;
            }
            else if (FirstCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("P", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                FirstCharacter = P;
            }
            else if (FirstCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("Q", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                FirstCharacter = Q;
            }
            else if (FirstCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("R", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                FirstCharacter = R;
            }
            else if (FirstCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("S", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                FirstCharacter = S;
            }
            else if (FirstCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("T", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                FirstCharacter = T;
            }
            else if (FirstCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("U", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                FirstCharacter = U;
            }
            else if (FirstCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("V", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                FirstCharacter = V;
            }
            else if (FirstCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("W", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                FirstCharacter = W;
            }
            else if (FirstCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("X", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                FirstCharacter = X;
            }
            else if (FirstCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("Y", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                FirstCharacter = Y;
            }
            else if (FirstCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("Z", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                FirstCharacter = Z;
            }

            //////////////////////////////////////////////////
            //                                              //
            //     SecondCharacter                          //
            //                                              //
            //////////////////////////////////////////////////

            if (SecondCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("A", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                SecondCharacter = A;
            }
            else if (SecondCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("B", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                SecondCharacter = B;
            }
            else if (SecondCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("C", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                SecondCharacter = C;
            }
            else if (SecondCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("D", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                SecondCharacter = D;
            }
            else if (SecondCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("E", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                SecondCharacter = E;
            }
            else if (SecondCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("F", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                SecondCharacter = F;
            }
            else if (SecondCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("G", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                SecondCharacter = G;
            }
            else if (SecondCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("H", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                SecondCharacter = H;
            }
            else if (SecondCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("I", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                SecondCharacter = I;
            }
            else if (SecondCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("J", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                SecondCharacter = J;
            }
            else if (SecondCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("K", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                SecondCharacter = K;
            }
            else if (SecondCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("L", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                SecondCharacter = L;
            }
            else if (SecondCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("M", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                SecondCharacter = M;
            }
            else if (SecondCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("N", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                SecondCharacter = N;
            }
            else if (SecondCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("O", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                SecondCharacter = O;
            }
            else if (SecondCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("P", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                SecondCharacter = P;
            }
            else if (SecondCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("Q", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                SecondCharacter = Q;
            }
            else if (SecondCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("R", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                SecondCharacter = R;
            }
            else if (SecondCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("S", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                SecondCharacter = S;
            }
            else if (SecondCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("T", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                SecondCharacter = T;
            }
            else if (SecondCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("U", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                SecondCharacter = U;
            }
            else if (SecondCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("V", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                SecondCharacter = V;
            }
            else if (SecondCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("W", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                SecondCharacter = W;
            }
            else if (SecondCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("X", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                SecondCharacter = X;
            }
            else if (SecondCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("Y", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                SecondCharacter = Y;
            }
            else if (SecondCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("Z", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                SecondCharacter = Z;
            }

            //////////////////////////////////////////////////
            //                                              //
            //     ThirdCharacter                           //
            //                                              //
            //////////////////////////////////////////////////

            if (ThirdCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("A", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                ThirdCharacter = A;
            }
            else if (ThirdCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("B", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                ThirdCharacter = B;
            }
            else if (ThirdCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("C", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                ThirdCharacter = C;
            }
            else if (ThirdCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("D", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                ThirdCharacter = D;
            }
            else if (ThirdCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("E", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                ThirdCharacter = E;
            }
            else if (ThirdCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("F", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                ThirdCharacter = F;
            }
            else if (ThirdCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("G", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                ThirdCharacter = G;
            }
            else if (ThirdCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("H", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                ThirdCharacter = H;
            }
            else if (ThirdCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("I", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                ThirdCharacter = I;
            }
            else if (ThirdCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("J", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                ThirdCharacter = J;
            }
            else if (ThirdCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("K", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                ThirdCharacter = K;
            }
            else if (ThirdCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("L", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                ThirdCharacter = L;
            }
            else if (ThirdCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("M", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                ThirdCharacter = M;
            }
            else if (ThirdCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("N", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                ThirdCharacter = N;
            }
            else if (ThirdCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("O", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                ThirdCharacter = O;
            }
            else if (ThirdCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("P", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                ThirdCharacter = P;
            }
            else if (ThirdCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("Q", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                ThirdCharacter = Q;
            }
            else if (ThirdCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("R", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                ThirdCharacter = R;
            }
            else if (ThirdCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("S", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                ThirdCharacter = S;
            }
            else if (ThirdCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("T", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                ThirdCharacter = T;
            }
            else if (ThirdCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("U", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                ThirdCharacter = U;
            }
            else if (ThirdCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("V", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                ThirdCharacter = V;
            }
            else if (ThirdCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("W", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                ThirdCharacter = W;
            }
            else if (ThirdCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("X", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                ThirdCharacter = X;
            }
            else if (ThirdCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("Y", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                ThirdCharacter = Y;
            }
            else if (ThirdCharacterTextBox.Text.Equals("Z", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                ThirdCharacter = Z;
            }

            MessageBox.Show(FirstCharacter + " " + SecondCharacter + " " + ThirdCharacter);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Adow]

[image: Convert]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to capitalise on the concept of better storage methods than a massive amount of `string`s.

Consider using a `Dictionary` instead:

> ```
>     private string A = "0NFGSosLPI";
>     private string B = "izNclMYrUO";
> ```

Into:

```
private Dictionary<string, string> letters = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    { "A", "0NFGSosLPI" },
    { "B", "izNclMYrUO" },

    // ...
};
```

However, I would still recommend moving this to another file to condense your code in this file, and in case you ever needed to call this Dictionary from another file.

And then, instead of your massive `if-else` loop, you can use a simple Dictionary lookup:

```
FirstCharacter = Letters[FirstCharacterTextBox.Text];
```

Additionally, instead of direct string concatenation, I'd recommend using `string.Format` instead, this can give you better control in more advanced situations:

> ```
> MessageBox.Show(FirstCharacter + " " + SecondCharacter + " " + ThirdCharacter);
> ```

into:

```
MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", FirstCharacter, SecondCharacter, ThirdCharacter);
```

You can even customise this format to make more advanced formats:

```
string.Format("Hi, {0}, we've received your payment of {1} on {2}. Thanks!", customer.Name, payment.Amount, payment.Date);
```

---

Effectively leaving you with:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Adow
{
    public partial class AdowForm : Form
    {
        private string FirstCharacter;
        private string SecondCharacter;
        private string ThirdCharacter;
        private Dictionary<string, string> letters = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            { "A", "0NFGSosLPI" },
            { "B", "izNclMYrUO" },
            { "C", "t7SjxAlxp5" },
            { "D", "CeA7dwvVxY" },
            { "E", "6kF4qi5bmt" },
            { "F", "WuuQpKLN7n" },
            { "G", "jy24ZxU7Ok" },
            { "H", "8j0RAVF1Ka" },
            { "I", "h9g173xKDV" },
            { "J", "ypEeaBAzBx" },
            { "K", "HNhqhtYMaU" },
            { "L", "4qUvzJfvRA" },
            { "M", "jJjAfk4m1y" },
            { "N", "iF9d70yyf5" },
            { "O", "9VlQkb0VKN" },
            { "P", "nEdrSFCVTO" },
            { "Q", "3ducfBmoi5" },
            { "R", "atWIdmnsnG" },
            { "S", "4edrAImSrq" },
            { "T", "aUhZY1uDA5" },
            { "U", "ARHxAVFnnN" },
            { "V", "VKNXzjDlrx" },
            { "W", "9eDu4vY24O" },
            { "X", "tWAspyXsMM" },
            { "Y", "DY89qcdHnP" },
            { "Z", "SNSjmtyVtw" }
        };

        public AdowForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ConvertButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FirstCharacter  = Letters[FirstCharacterTextBox.Text.ToUpperInvariant()];
            SecondCharacter = Letters[SecondCharacterTextBox.Text.ToUpperInvariant()];
            ThirdCharacter  = Letters[ThirdCharacterTextBox.Text.ToUpperInvariant()];

            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", FirstCharacter, SecondCharacter, ThirdCharacter);
        }
    }
}
```

But, you should also do a `Letters.ContainsKey` check to make sure that the letter you're trying to look up is in the dictionary.

Comment: This doesn't do quite the same thing as the original code, as the original code works regardless of casing (yours only works on uppercase letters), and your dictionary lookup will throw an exception if not found.

Comment: @eurotrash is right.  Your `ConvertButton_Click` method should be corrected along the lines of `FirstCharacterTextBox.Text` should be `FirstCharacterTextBox.Text.ToUpperInvariant()`, and so on.

Comment: Ah, thanks for informing me, I'll fix it ASAP :-)

Comment: @Quill Thank you very much for the explanatory answer.